# How to copy projects into workspace of eclipse after importing the project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I imported a project into eclipse but incidentally I forgot to check-mark the checkbox "copy projects into workspace" option. Now after wards(importing has been done) Is there any way through which I can copy the project into the workspace.

Also, while importing a maven project into eclipse which option should I select in order to copy the project into the workspace?

Comment: Why not delete project from eclipse, import again and don't forget to check that option?

Comment: good idea :D did it several times bevore, too so it will surely work ^^

Comment: thanks but thts an obvious solution but is there any other option available?

Comment: Doing things manually in Eclipse that should be done through Eclipsefunctionality is often a good way to get into trouble. Delete, then import again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

delete project (JUST FROM WORKSPACE, it will prompt you on delete with check box) and re import it